# ExecutorService shutdown hook

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have console application with following threading code. It seems when i hit ***Ctrl+C*** to terminate it does not detect control keys, i have to close command prompt window.

***Any clues why it is not detecting ctrl+c?***

```
            final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        final long SHUTDOWN_TIME = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            executor.submit(new MessageWorker(topicSubscriber));
        }
        //--
        //Add JVM shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            /**
             * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
             */
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executor.shutdown();
                try {
                    if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        log.warn("Executor did not terminate in the specified time.");
                        List<Runnable> droppedTasks = executor.shutdownNow();
                        log.warn("Executor was abruptly shut down. " + droppedTasks.size() + " tasks will not be executed.");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What actually happens? Does program quit but, but hook is not called?

Comment: program simply does not quit.

Comment: Do you start it `java -jar` from command prompt?

Comment: yes, `java -server -jar mypro.jar -Xmx1024m` etc...

Comment: You press Ctrl+C in the same console? It has nothing to do with hook it is something else.

Comment: i believe when Ctrl+C is key pressed on console, it signals JVM SIGINT which interrupt the threads... which in turns invokes shutdown hook???

Comment: It is supposed to be like that. But even though you don't have a hook, JVM should stop when Ctrl+C is received. Hook just allows you to do additional clean-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a guess from reading the code, but, it looks like your shutdown time is set as 10,000 seconds, so I'm not surprised you don't think it's quitting!

```
    final long SHUTDOWN_TIME = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);
    ...
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(SHUTDOWN_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
```

Comment: wow, so it is possible to postpone termination for such a long time even though Ctrl+C is received?

Comment: Most signals (TERM, HUP, CUSTOM, etc) can be blocked completely actually, the danger of doing so is that the caller may choose to send a signal you cannot block. (KILL, etc)